# How to execute MonkeyRunner from Yii webpage and Python

Tags: php, android, python, yii2, monkeyrunner

I have Installed LAMP, Yii Framework 2, Android SDK path are defined. and the code of CallTest.php (using Yii) that call a Python Script is like this:

```
$EmuListOnline = Yii::app()->params['pathfilesscript']."ListAVDs-Online.txt";
$UserList = Yii::app()->params['pathfilesscript'].'UserListAVDs.txt';
$ScriptStartTest = Yii::app()->params['pathfilesscript'].'TestAVDs.py';
$DebugLog = Yii::app()->params['pathfilesscript'].'debug.log';

$cmd = 'python '.$ScriptStartTest.' '.$EmuListOnline.' '.$UserList.' > '.$DebugLog.' 2>&1';
$output1 = shell_exec($cmd);
if ($output1) {
    echo "Starting<br>";
    echo $output1;
} else {
echo "Not Executed";
var_dump($output1); }
```

The PythonScript call MonkeyRunner, adb, and others android commands. When I execute TestAVDs.py from command Line it works, But If I Call it from Yii  it return as NULL and in log shows this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: monkeyrunner: not found
```

Code of TestAVDs.py below. I change shell_exec by exec; write the path on code but doesn't work.

```
for index, line in enumerate(listdevtotest):
  emulatorid = listdevtotest[index][0]
  deviceid = listdevtotest[index][1]
  subprocess.call('monkeyrunner -v ALL Test1.py ' + emulatorid + ' ' + deviceid + ' ' + str(index), shell=True)
```

Some ideas to execute my TestAVDs.py from Yii webpage. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the absolute path of monkeyrunner or set the PATH environment variable before invoking the script. For example:

```
subprocess.call('/path/to/monkeyrunner -v ALL Test1.py ' + emulatorid + ' ' + deviceid + ' ' + str(index), shell=True)
```

Comment: NP. I noticed you are running tests on multiple devices, you should take a look at http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2015/05/android-culebra-multi-device.html